# How to see the linkage of widget in android studio for flutter programming

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I want to ask how can i see the linkage of widget tree in android studio for flutter?

I had seen some tutorial series as showing the linkage like this
[image]

But for my case is showing like this.
[image]

is there any setting that I need to turn on/off?

Comment: I had the same problem and i fixed it upgrading Android Studio

Comment: Thanks upgrading Android Studio solve the problem.